# Splitting hashpower over multiple pools

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, scrypt

Is it possible to split the mining hashpower of a rented mining rig over multiple pools simultaneously?

Say, I rent a scrypt mining power of 5 Mh/s. What I want to do is point that rig to a stratum tcp port on a VPS/dedicated server that I own, and then "funnel" the total hashpower to mine on different pools from the VPS using cpuminer/gpuminer. Is that possible?